# How to Send Keyboard Command to Android Tv using TLSManager in swift

Tags: swift, remote-control, remote-connection, mpremotecommandcenter

I am developing a Remote App for Android TV in Swift, utilizing TLSClientManager to send commands. Initially, I successfully implemented functionality for numeric and basic keys. However, I am now encountering difficulties integrating keyboard input into the application.

I attempted to research online resources and documentation related to TLSClientManager and keyboard input integration in Swift for Android TV. However, I haven't found a clear solution that addresses my specific requirements.

I expected to find guidance or insights on how to incorporate keyboard input functionality seamlessly into my Remote App, allowing users to input text and navigate using their device's keyboard while maintaining TLSClientManager functionality for sending commands.